# Calculating Cook's Distance in R manually...running into issues with the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

I have been trying to calculate Cook's distance manually for a multiple linear regression dataset, but running into problems with the for loop. What I have been doing is this:

This is the original linear model, and the associated fitted values, length = 'n'.

```
{fitted = lm10$fitted.values}
```

This is the new, n X n, blank matrix,  I created to hold the new fitted values.

```
{lev.mat <- matrix(rep(0, nrow(X.des)^2), nrow = nrow(X.des))}
```

I wanted to save time, so I filled in the first column of the matrix manually.

```
{newData = as.data.frame(X.des[-1,])
newModel = lm(fev~., data = newData - 1)
newFitted = newModel$fitted.values
newDist = c(fitted[1],newFitted)
lev.mat[,1] = newDist}
```

I then tried to fill in the rest of the columns of the lev.mat similarly, using the for loop.

```
 for(i in 2:nrow(lev.mat)){
 newData = as.data.frame(X.des[-i, ])
 newModel = lm(fev~., data = newData - 1)
 newFitted = newModel$fitted.values
 newDist = c(newFitted[1:(i-1)],fitted[i],newFitted[i:length(newFitted)])
 lev.mat[,i] = newDist
 }
```

But I keep getting this error repeatedly:

```
 {Error in lev.mat[, i] <- newDist : 
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length}
```

I have been at this for three hours now, and it's getting frustrating. Can anybody point out the error and help me move along? My net steps are to calculate the difference between the original fitted values and each column of values in the new fitted values matrix, sum the differences, and divide by the product of the number of predictors and the MSE.

Thanks!

Comment: Should your new dist in the loop be `newFitted[(i+1):length(newFitted)]`?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth: newDist has length (n-1), since I am fitting it with dataset with only (n-1) observations. but lev.mat[,i] has a length n. I am adding the 'i'th observation from the 'fitted' vector to make the lengths equal.

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208242/hat-matrix-and-leverages-in-classical-multiple-regression

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to @Harlan Nelson for providing me with a wonderful link! I used the background provided in the link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208242/hat-matrix-and-leverages-in-classical-multiple-regression) to complete my work. Here is the rest of my code:

```
Hmat = hatvalues(lm10)

Leverage = Hmat/(1 - Hmat)

mse = (lm10$residuals)^2/var(lm10$residuals)

CooksD <- (1/6)*(mse)*Leverage
```

lm10 was the name of my linear model, and I had 6 predictors in the model. This helped me calculate Cook's Distance for the model. Thanks again!